# Apache Ant exec error

Tags: xml, apache, ant

When I try to run "ant" in the CLI, I get the BUILD FAILED "Execute failed: java.in.IOException: Cannot run program "phploc": CreateProcess error=2" error (at the exec executable="phploc" line).

My file structure:
-- build/
-- src/
-- build.xml

Build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="..." default="build">
 <target name="build"
   depends="prepare,phploc,pdepend,phpmd-ci,phpcs-ci,phpcpd,phpdox,phpunit,phpcb"/>

 <target name="build-parallel"
   depends="prepare,tools-parallel,phpunit,phpcb"/>

 <target name="tools-parallel" description="Run tools in parallel">
  <parallel threadCount="2">
   <sequential>
    <antcall target="pdepend"/>
    <antcall target="phpmd-ci"/>
   </sequential>
   <antcall target="phpcpd"/>
   <antcall target="phpcs-ci"/>
   <antcall target="phploc"/>
   <antcall target="phpdox"/>
  </parallel>
 </target>

 <target name="clean" description="Cleanup build artifacts">
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/api"/>
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/code-browser"/>
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/coverage"/>
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/logs"/>
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build/pdepend"/>
 </target>

 <target name="prepare" depends="clean" description="Prepare for build">
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/api"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/code-browser"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/coverage"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/logs"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/pdepend"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/phpdox"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phploc" description="Measure project size using PHPLOC">
  <exec executable="phploc">
   <arg value="--log-csv" />
   <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/phploc.csv" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src/" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="pdepend" description="Calculate software metrics using PHP_Depend">
  <exec executable="pdepend">
   <arg value="--jdepend-xml=${basedir}/build/logs/jdepend.xml" />
   <arg value="--jdepend-chart=${basedir}/build/pdepend/dependencies.svg" />
   <arg value="--overview-pyramid=${basedir}/build/pdepend/overview-pyramid.svg" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src/application" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpmd"
         description="Perform project mess detection using PHPMD and print human readable output. Intended for usage on the command line before committing.">
  <exec executable="phpmd">
   <arg path="${basedir}/src/application" />
   <arg value="text" />
   <arg value="${basedir}/build/phpmd.xml" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpmd-ci" description="Perform project mess detection using PHPMD creating a log file for the continuous integration server">
  <exec executable="phpmd">
   <arg path="${basedir}/src/application" />
   <arg value="xml" />
   <arg value="${basedir}/build/phpmd.xml" />
   <arg value="--reportfile" />
   <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/pmd.xml" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcs"
         description="Find coding standard violations using PHP_CodeSniffer and print human readable output. Intended for usage on the command line before committing.">
  <exec executable="phpcs">
   <arg value="--standard=${basedir}/build/phpcs.xml" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src/application" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcs-ci" description="Find coding standard violations using PHP_CodeSniffer creating a log file for the continuous integration server">
  <exec executable="phpcs" output="/dev/null">
   <arg value="--report=checkstyle" />
   <arg value="--report-file=${basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml" />
   <arg value="--standard=${basedir}/build/phpcs.xml" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src/application" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcpd" description="Find duplicate code using PHPCPD">
  <exec executable="phpcpd">
   <arg value="--log-pmd" />
   <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src/application" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="phpdox" description="Generate API documentation using phpDox">
  <exec executable="phpdox"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
  <exec executable="phpunit" failonerror="true"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpcb" description="Aggregate tool output with PHP_CodeBrowser">
  <exec executable="phpcb">
   <arg value="--log" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/logs" />
   <arg value="--source" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
   <arg value="--output" />
   <arg path="${basedir}/build/code-browser" />
  </exec>
 </target>
</project>
```

Could you provide me some suggestions on how to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 2 means "file not found", which suggests the command you're trying to run isn't on your PATH.  But note also that Ant's `exec` task uses Java's `Runtime.exec` under the covers, which on Windows can only run `.exe` commands, not `.bat` files.  To run a batch file you need to use

```
<exec executable="cmd">
  <arg value="/c" />
  <arg file="C:/path/to/phploc.bat" />
  <arg value="--log-csv" />
  <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/phploc.csv" />
  <arg path="${basedir}/src/" />
</exec>
```